# Get a list of most popular contracts and transaction count

Tags: tokens, etherscan

How can I list the top 1000 popular ethereum contracts? I want to know the contract address and transaction count.

Is there any API or website that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [ERC20 Top Tokens](https://etherscan.io/tokens)
- [ERC721 Top Tokens](https://etherscan.io/tokens-nft)
- [ERC201155 Top Tokens](https://etherscan.io/tokens-nft1155)
- [coinmarketcap's list](https://coinmarketcap.com/)
- [etherscan's API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens)

Hope this helps.